# Undefined on a function result

Tags: javascript

I wrote this functions which correctly log the value that I expected (an array of partecipants id only):

```
getPartecipantsList: function(roomId){
        this._getPartecipants(roomId,function(err,data){
            partecipants_to_send = [];
            for (i=0; i< data.partecipants.length; i++){
                partecipants_to_send.push({ id : data.partecipants[i].id });
            }
            console.log(partecipants_to_send);
            return partecipants_to_send;
        });
    },
```

The log shows something like this:

> [ { id: 'user1' } , { id: 'user2'} ]

When I try to call this function from my middleware, it doesn't show the same values (instead it gives me `undefined`):

```
...
router.route('/:id/partecipants')
    .get(function(req,res){
        partecipants_list = RoomsManager.getPartecipantsList(req.room._id);
        console.log(partecipants_list);
....
```

How can I get the value that I expected on my middleware?

This code is running on a Node.js back-end

Comment: Check if  req.room._id is what you think it is

Comment: What's the output of `req.room._id`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: whats this._getPartecipants ? is it a sync function?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your return statement is returning from an anonymous function to this._getPartecipants, but the result from this._getPartecipants is not being returned to you.

Try:

```
getPartecipantsList: function(roomId){
    return this._getPartecipants(roomId,function(err,data){
        partecipants_to_send = [];
        for (i=0; i< data.partecipants.length; i++){
            partecipants_to_send.push({ id : data.partecipants[i].id });
        }
        console.log(partecipants_to_send);
        return partecipants_to_send;
    });
},
```

Comment: I understood that the problem is due to the return statement, but the solution propose doesn't work